# Updating Array Values Incrementally Overwrites The Existing Values, Why?

Tags: serial, programming, c++, arduino-pro-mini, array

I have a global array. I'd like to update the array while the program running.
But, I've found that my program below doesn't work as I expected.

**Please checkout the program source:**

```
#define RespLength 10
char* response[] = {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
int idxUpd  = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    char assign[5];
    int wkt = random(10, 99);
    dtostrf(wkt, 4, 1, assign);

    response[idxUpd]  = assign;

    Serial.print("Iteration "+String(idxUpd)+" : ");
    for (int i=0;i<RespLength;i++){
        Serial.print(response[i]);Serial.print(",");
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(500);

    idxUpd++;
    idxUpd = idxUpd >= 10 ? 0 : idxUpd;
}
```

**Expected output:** please concern to the patern

```
Iteration 0 : 12.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 1 : 12.2,23.7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 2 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 3 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 4 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 5 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,10.1,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 6 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,10.1,11.6,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 7 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,10.1,11.6,78.9,0,0,0,
Iteration 8 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,10.1,11.6,78.9,98.2,0,0,
Iteration 9 : 12.2,23.7,65.3,15.9,10.1,11.6,78.9,98.2,68.6,90.1,
```

**Current output:**

```
Iteration 0 : 85.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 1 : 28.0,28.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 2 : 36.0,36.0,36.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 3 : 70.0,70.0,70.0,70.0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 4 : 56.0,56.0,56.0,56.0,56.0,0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 5 : 74.0,74.0,74.0,74.0,74.0,74.0,0,0,0,0,
Iteration 6 : 94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,0,0,0,
Iteration 7 : 94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,94.0,0,0,
Iteration 8 : 26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,26.0,0,
Iteration 9 : 71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,71.0,
```

From the result above, I can conclude that if I update the array value incrementally, it just overwrites the other element in the array.
So, How can I have my `expected output`?

Answer (score 3):

You are using a char pointer (char*) instead of a char.

When you say;

```
response[idxUpd]  = assign;
```

you are assigning not the value but a pointer to that value. That points to `assign` for every element in `response[]`. Every `response[]` get the same pointer value, every `response[]` get the same value.

Use this:

```
#define RespLength 10
int response[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int idxUpd  = 0;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    int wkt = random(10, 99);
    response[idxUpd]  = wkt;

    Serial.print("Iteration "); Serial.print(idxUpd); Serial.print(" : ");
    for (int i=0;i<RespLength;i++){
        Serial.print(response[i] );Serial.print(",");
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(500);

    idxUpd++;
    idxUpd = idxUpd >= 10 ? 0 : idxUpd;
}
```

I don't understand why you are converting a `int` to a `float`. That value doesn't change, so I omitted the `dtostr()` call.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell the story. So, I'm using `char*` because the response will be passed into `Wire.write()`. That function needs the parameter to be `char*`. I've tried to make the response as `int` or `float`, but it is not working well when passed to `Wire.write()` like this `Wire.write(String(response[idxResp]).c)str())`;

Comment: @Oki. You can use `Wire.write(value)`, where `value` is a byte. An unsigned byte can take values from 0-255. You can send `int` and `float` if you send them byte by byte. It's better keep you data as binary and convert it to string as needed. Study pointers and you will be a Master.

Comment: I did read about pointers and etc some times ago. But my bad, I forget it because I'm not used to this programming style and language. I accept your suggestion. I changed the  `char* response[]` to `String response[]` instead of `float response[]`,  I do this to minimize the conversion process.

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ Arrays don't work the way you are used from scripting languages.
Your

```
char* response[] = {"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"};
```

allocates a consecutive space in memory with the lenght of 20 bytes.
So you have 10 pointers that point to static memory.

In your loop you have a array of `char assign[5]` that gets assigned to every single of those pointers with `response[idxUpd]  = assign;`. You copy **pointers** and **not values** here. So the only value you really have is that in your `assign` variable. So as you update the pointes of the array, you get the results you see.

Comment: I thought the pointer is `char *response` not `char* response` :D. Now I know why `sizeof(response)` returns 20.

Comment: @Oki. A pointer in Arduino takes 2 bytes. You have a 10 elements (pointers) array, then 20 bytes. `sizeof` gives you the size in bytes of the argument.